# Using turn.js I'm trying to have the first page of the corner already flipped in on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have turn.js set up similarly to the way you see here : http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/03/instagram-magazine-php-jquery/

I would like to have the top right corner of first page already bent in as if I had hovered over it as soon as the page is loaded.

I'm brand new to JS so looking at https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/wiki/Reference and taking a wild guess I wrote this

```
document.getElementById('magazine').onload = function() 
{    
    $('#magazine').turn('tr', 1);
}
```

This of course doesn't do anything except embarrass me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would set an option:

```
$(function() 
{    
    $('#magazine').turn({ tr : 1 });
});
```

sadly tr is not an option so it won't help.  I don't believe there is an option to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hope code would show "peeled" page when page loaded:

```
$('#magazine').turn({gradients: true, acceleration: true});
$('#magazine').turn('peel', 'br');
```

see reference:

http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Method:_peel